# Django: connection to DB throw custom driver

Tags: django, apache, mongodb

I have Django project that use PostgreSQL as main backend:

```
settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3, 'oracle'.
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        ...
    },
}
```

But I also have custom connection to MongoDB in my application:

```
mongo_connection.py

from pymongo import Connection
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
from django.db import connections

try:  
    connection = Connection(host="127.0.0.1", port=27017)
    db = connection[db_name]
    print "Connected successfully(Mongo, %s)" % (db_name,)
except ConnectionFailure, e:
    sys.stderr.write("Could not connect to MongoDB: %s" % e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

On production server I noticed one thing in Apache's error.log:

```
[Wed May 23 05:05:39 2012] [error] Connected successfully(Mongo, galio)
[Wed May 23 05:07:16 2012] [error] Connected successfully(Mongo, galio)
[Wed May 23 06:41:51 2012] [error] Connected successfully(Mongo, galio)
[Wed May 23 06:42:21 2012] [error] Connected successfully(Mongo, galio)
...
[Wed May 23 19:26:45 2012] [error] Connected successfully(Mongo, galio)
[Wed May 23 19:26:48 2012] [error] Connected successfully(Mongo, galio)
[Wed May 23 22:20:44 2012] [error] Connected successfully(Mongo, galio)
[Wed May 23 22:20:48 2012] [error] Connected successfully(Mongo, galio)
[Thu May 24 00:12:45 2012] [error] Connected successfully(Mongo, galio)
```

It means that Apache occasionally reimport modules(am I right?). I have two questions:

1) Does this behavior normal for production server? 
2) Where is the best place to put custom connection? May be I should move this code to settings.py?

P.S. Apache config

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAdmin it@asdf.as 
    ServerName ... 
    ServerAlias ... 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ 
    LogLevel warn 
    WSGIDaemonProcess www-data processes=2 maximum-requests=500 threads=1
    WSGIProcessGroup www-data 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/disk/galio/galio/apache/django.wsgi 
    Alias /media /var/www/media/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How are you running your app (mod_wsgi, mod_python, fcgi, whatever)?

Comment: Then show your Apache config (relevant part).

Comment: # cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin it@asdf.as
    ServerName ...
    ServerAlias ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ 
    LogLevel warn
    WSGIDaemonProcess www-data processes=2 maximum-requests=500 threads=1
    WSGIProcessGroup www-data
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/disk/galio/galio/apache/django.wsgi
    Alias /media /var/www/media/
    </VirtualHost>

Comment: It's absolutely unreadable. Please add it to question body or put on external pastebin service.